# How to add / Modify Right Click options in a webpage

Tags: php, html, right-click

I want to change right click values which clicking on a particular item on a WebPage and make right click values to functioning. I am a PHP developer..

Kindly see the image below

http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_EzIJxJICfGw/TOuRqAkAn6I/AAAAAAAAAHo/cHERiyuPo90/s1600/right_click.jpg

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery, you can try http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/right-click-menu.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the default rightclick menu that the browser draws for you. You can, however, prevent the default behavior of the rightclick-event and draw your own menu (made up of HTML and CSS) at the cursor position. This requires some JavaScript knowlege, though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at javascript as this is largely clientside behaviour
Maybe somethign like [this jquery plugin](http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/09/jquery-context-menu-plugin/)

Then you can call php via ajax